# entity sql count null

Tags: sql, entity-framework-5, entity-sql

I'm having trouble with counting null values using Entity SQL.

Code in SQL:

```
SELECT Table.City, COUNT(*)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Table.City
```

and in Linq to Entities:

```
var query1 = from g in context.Table
             group g by g.City into mygroup
             select new { mygroup, c = mygroup.Count() };
```

both return **correct** values:

```
NULL    4
Boston  7
Canberra    1
London  5
Melbourne   5
New York    4
Paris   15
Sydney  4
```

**However**, Entity SQL code written like:

```
string queryString1 = "SELECT city, COUNT(g.City)" +
                      "FROM Entities.Table AS g " +
                      "GROUP BY g.City as city";
```

returns:

```
NULL    0
Boston  7
Canberra    1
London  5
Melbourne   5
New York    4
Paris   15
Sydney  4
```

Why are the NULLs not counted properly? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**How Entity SQL Differs from Transact-SQL**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738573.aspx)

> Entity SQL does not support the count(*) aggregate. Use count(0) instead.

Usually `COUNT(*)` counts rows while `COUNT(g.City)` gives you NOT NULL values amount.